# How do I ensure best signal performance when using a 2.92 mm (K) connector that is compression mounted on my PCB?

Tags: pcb, rf, connector

I am concerned that because the recommended PCB layout shows the signal pad completely surrounded by the GND pad, I will need a via in order to route the signal. I am using this K connector instead of a standard SMA connector, because I want the best performance when using 20+ GHz signals. From my understanding, vias are to be avoided when designing RF PCBs. Is it not a big deal as long as the length of the via is considerably less than the effective "wavelength" of the signal? What about the fact that the via introduces a 90 degree bend?

Here is a link to the part's datasheet: [2.92MM JACK 2HOLE FL MT
W/ 0-80 UNF THD](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/18/1521-60013.SF.PDD_0-787702.pdf)

Thanks in advance for everyone's responses!

Comment: What Ali says is right, ask the vendor. They will probably have you placing ground vias around your signal via to form an approximately coaxial structure. You can not route out from that connector on the top layer because the body of the connector directly above the trace would disturb the transmission line properties. If you want to avoid this, use edge-mount connectors.

Comment: If your via is connected on an inner layer rather than the bottom layer, they may also have you use microvias, blind vias, or back-drilling to avoid a stub of "unused" via hanging off the actual signal path.

Answer (score 1):

To get any reasonable performance out of this "compression-mount" connector, you need to contact its manufacturer and request drawings of fan-out pattern for their product, a real PCB test layout with full manufacturing information for stack-up, and request network analyzer data from them. If you want to get anything at 20+ GHz, you better get a 3-D electrical model for the connector, and have a good CAD tools that can model your PCB elements and traces. Then you would need to try different layouts three-four times (either three-four different test coupons on one board, or several board spins), and run your test coupons on good network analyzer until you get acceptable performance.